# How to create a unique pairwise list of a column value based on table entry and its referenced entry in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, list

Im trying to extract the following information from the oracle table below: A list of all the unique  pairwise Status combinations for entries and their referenced entries. Entries with no referenced entry will be ignored. For example, for the entry 10 I expect the output to be (1,3) because its status is 1 and the status of the referenced entry 7 is 3. If the list doesn't already have this combination, it should be added to the list. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? I'm totally clueless as to how to even google what I want to achieve.

[image: table with entry ID and status and referenced entry ID]

EDIT: The first column is the ID of the entry, the second column is the status of the entry, and the third column is the ID of another entry in the same table that is referenced.

Comment: OK, you said that for rows whose REF_ID is NULL can be ignored (that's 5 rows in your sample data). Then, for ID = 2 you want to get (1, 3) as result. As all other rows (whose REF_ID isn't null) have unique (STATUS, REF_ID) combination, does it mean that the final result is actually 5 pairs? (1, 3), (6, 6), (0, 1), (5, 9) and (2, 7)? Or ...?

Comment: I'm sorry, the table wasn't representative of the much much larger table, lm working with. so I changed it slightly. Currently the above table has the following unique status pairs: (1,3), (6,4),(0,0),(5,2).

Comment: I'm sorry too, because I don't see where pairs (you mentioned in the comment) are displayed on the screenshot. Except for (1, 3), there are no other pairs there. Or - another possibility - I don't understand the question.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I hope, it's clearer now. The pairs are not displayed on the screenshot. They are yet to be created based on the data in the table

Comment: Aha; I think I got it. Have a look at answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a self join:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, status, ref_id) as
  2    (select  1, 0, null from dual union all
  3     select  2, 1, 3    from dual union all
  4     select  3, 3, null from dual union all
  5     select  4, 6, 6    from dual union all
  6     select  5, 0, 1    from dual union all
  7     select  6, 4, null from dual union all
  8     select  7, 3, null from dual union all
  9     select  8, 5, 9    from dual union all
 10     select  9, 2, null from dual union all
 11     select 10, 1, 7    from dual
 12    )
```

Query:

```
 13  select a.id, a.status, b.status
 14  from test a join test b on b.id = a.ref_id
 15  where a.ref_id is not null
 16  order by a.id;

        ID     STATUS     STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1          3
         4          6          4
         5          0          0
         8          5          2
        10          1          3

SQL>
```

---

If you want to get *distinct* pairs (but still know IDs involved), you could use `listagg` (it'll work as long as resulting string doesn't exceed 4000 characters; if it does, use `xmlagg` instead):

```
 13  select listagg(a.id, ', ') within group (order by a.id) id,
 14         a.status, b.status
 15  from test a join test b on b.id = a.ref_id
 16  where a.ref_id is not null
 17  group by a.status, b.status
 18  order by id;

ID                       STATUS     STATUS
-------------------- ---------- ----------
2, 10                         1          3
4                             6          4
5                             0          0
8                             5          2

SQL>
```

---

If you don't care about IDs, then

```
 13  select distinct a.status, b.status
 14  from test a join test b on b.id = a.ref_id
 15  where a.ref_id is not null
 16  order by a.status, b.status;

    STATUS     STATUS
---------- ----------
         0          0
         1          3
         5          2
         6          4

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! not quite but almost what l wanted.. The last entry has a status pair of (1,3), which is already there. but l think l can still work with this query.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info (two more queries); have a look, please.

Comment: I don't care about the IDs. Now that solves my problem completely. Thanks!